# Spring Social Security with separate BE and FE

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social

Currently we have an application where we have username/password authentication and social  authentication with facebook and googel.
Back end is in Spring Boot and Front end is a AngularJS application.
For social authentication we use satellizer and on back end we send code, redirectUrl and clienId from front end side and back end send request for accessToken. After we found user we send jwt token on front end.

Now, we want integrate Spring Social.

And our question is Can we implement Spring Social Security on this kind of architecture?

We have back end, front end and android and we use REST full service.